# Why BER-TLV "DF9A" tag is recognized as "invalid"?

Tags: tlv

I have problem with understanding why all the BER-TLV parsers I found:

- https://paymentcardtools.com/emv-tlv-parser
- https://emvlab.org/tlvutils/
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tlv-parser/iemijfhdlipdpcjfnphcdalpccnkfedb

Recognize this tag: `DF9A03001736` as "invalid", while: `DF5603001736` and `DF0903001736` work just fine.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just follow the description provided in [EMV Book 3, Annex B1](https://www.emvco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/EMV_v4.3_Book_3_Application_Specification_20120607062110791.pdf)

"invalid" case: DF9A03001736

```
DF - 1101 1111
9A - 1001 1010 - here, in the second byte of the Tag, the b8 is set (1), which means that 'Another byte follows', so the following byte (value 03) is also part of the Tag
03 - 0000 0011 - the last byte of the Tag, i.e. the actual Tag is DF9A03
```

so, in our sequence we have:

```
DF9A03 - Tag
00 - Length (no value)
17 - is already a new Tag
36 - length of the Tag 17 ...
```

So the parser (https://paymentcardtools.com/emv-tlv-parser) fails because no data is available (Error during parsing Tag 17: Not enough data)

correct example: DF5603001736

```
DF - 1101 1111
56 - 0101 0110 - there are no more bytes that constitute Tag, so we just have Tag DF56
```

the sequence is:

```
DF56 - Tag
03 - Length
001736 - Value
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That explains everything!